# How to navigate between multiple pages in one frame, in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have :

- MainWindow.xaml (*where I have the frame*)
- LoginPage.xaml
- SignUpPage.xaml

Here is the frame in MainWindow.xaml:

```
  <Frame x:Name="MainPage"
               Content="{Binding ApplicationViewModel.CurentPage,
                                Source={x:Static viewMod:ViewModelLocator.Instanze},
                                Converter={local:ApplicationPageValueConverter}}"/>
```

`ApplicationViewModel` is the application state as a view model :

```
 public class ApplicationViewModel 
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// The current page of the application
    /// </summary>
    public ApplicationPage CurentPage { get; set; } = ApplicationPage.Login;
 }
```

`ViewModelLocator` locates view models from the `IoC` for use in binding in Xaml files

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Singleton instance of the locator
   /// </summary>
   public static ViewModelLocator Instance { get; private set; } = new ViewModelLocator();

   /// <summary>
   /// The application view model
   /// </summary>
   public static ApplicationViewModel ApplicationViewModel => IoC.Get<ApplicationViewModel>();   
 }
```

In `ApplicationPageValueConverter` I have this, to convert the page:

```
public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
          
  switch ((ApplicationPage)value)
  {
      case ApplicationPage.Login:
           return new LoginPage(); 
                
      case ApplicationPage.SignUp:
           return new SignUpPage();

      default:
        Debugger.Break();
         return null;
   }
}
```

In the `MainViewModel` which is `ViewModel` for MainWindow.xaml.cs I have a button "SignUp", and when I click the button is going to execute `ICommand` whose is doing this:

```
public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }      
LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Login());

private void Login()
{
  IoC.Get<ApplicationViewModel>().CurentPage = ApplicationPage.SignUp;
}
```

The value of `ApplicationViewModel.CurentPage` *is changed* to `ApplicationPage.SignUp` but it doesn't go to `ApplicationPageValueConverter` to convert/show the page.

Here is the `IoC` [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szdGZ.png) where `OnStartup` I'm doing this :

```
base.OnStartup(e);

IoC.SetUp();
....
```

I can't get whay it doesn't show the page, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ApplicationViewModel` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever the `CurrentPage` property is set:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ApplicationPage _currentPage = ApplicationPage.Login;

    /// <summary>
    /// The current page of the application
    /// </summary>
    public ApplicationPage CurentPage
    {
        get { return _currentPage; }
        set { _currentPage = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

This is required for the view to be notified of the change and the converter to get invoked again.